# Bash: multiple conditions in if to check a parameter

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So, to run my script I use a parameter like this:

```
./script 789
```

The parameter is to change the permissions of a file or a directory, and I'd like to check if every digit is between 0 and 7, so what I tried is the next thing:

```
 if [[ ${1:0:1} -ge 0 && ${1:0:1} -le 7 ]] && [[ ${1:1:1} -ge 0 && ${1:1:1} -le 7]] && [[ ${1:2:1} -ge 0 && ${1:2:1} -le 7]]
 then {go ahead with the code}
 else 
     echo "Error: each digit in the parameter must be between 0 and 7"
 fi
```

If it's true, then go ahead with the script, else show an error message, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Compare $1 with the regex `[0-7][0-7][0-7]`

Comment: a single char cannot be a negative number,

Comment: @WilliamPursell how do I do that?

Comment: Thank you all guys, this have been so helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to match the parameter with the regex `[0-7][0-7][0-7]`, or `[0-7]{3}`.  In bash, you can do:

```
[[ "$1" =~ [0-7]{3} ]] || { echo 'invalid parameter' >&2; exit 1; }
```

Or:

```
echo "$1" | grep -Eq '[0-7]{3}' || { echo err message >&2; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I've got another question, what does that >&2 do?

Comment: The `>&2` redirects the output of echo to stderr.  It is an error message, and error messages belong on stderr.

Comment: This may seem trivial, since if you run the script as a one-off command from the command line both stderr and stdout are associated with the tty, but it is good practice and will become important when your tools are used as filters (chained in a pipeline).

Comment: You can use `[0-7]{3}` in `bash` as well; there's no need for `grep` here.

Comment: I didn't intend to imply that {n} cannot be used in bash, but was merely demonstrating the use of grep.  Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.  I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

this could be another way

```
#!/bin/bash

#Stored input parameter 1 in a variable
perm="$1"

#Checking if inserted parameter is empty, in that case the script will show a help
if [ -z "${perm}" ];then
        echo "Usage: $0 <permission>"
        echo "I.e.: $0 777"
        exit
else
        #if the parameter is not empy, check if each digit is between 0-7
        check=`echo $perm| grep [0-7][0-7][0-7]`
        #if the result of command is empty that means that the input parameter contains at least one digit that's differs from 0-7
        if [ -z "${check}" ];then
                echo "Error: each digit in the parameter must be between 0 and 7"
        fi
fi
```

that's the output

```
[shell] ➤ ./test9.ksh 999
Error: each digit in the parameter must be between 0 and 7

[shell] ➤ ./test9.ksh 789
Error: each digit in the parameter must be between 0 and 7

[shell] ➤ ./test9.ksh 779
Error: each digit in the parameter must be between 0 and 7

[shell] ➤ ./test9.ksh 777
```

Comment: Can I get a breif explanation of this? I'm kinda new to shell script and don't know what most of those commands do

Comment: Checking that the result of `grep` is non-empty is *not* the correct way to use `grep` for this sort of thing.  Use the exit status instead.  eg, `if echo string | grep -q pattern; then`

Comment: I've added some comments in the script

Comment: Using `ksh` as the extension for a `bash` script is a bit misleading.